# N points on circle. How many regions can circle be divided into?

Tags: geometry

If there are N points on a circle, and you draw a chord between each of them, how many regions is the circle subdivided into

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_a_circle_into_areas

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyChords.html